# Функция не обменивает значения местами,не могу понять почему

Tags: c++, функции

Вроде все сделал,ошибок вижуал студио не выдает,но значения местами менять отказывается.
Приложу код,возможно все это из-за неопытности

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void shiftRight3(int a, int b,int c)
{
    swap(a, b);
    swap(c, a);
}
int main()
{
    int a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, c2;
    cout << "Input a1,b1,c1:"; cin >> a1>>b1>>c1;
    shiftRight3(a1, b1, c1);
    cout << "New numbers are " << a1 << setw(3) << b1 << setw(3) << c1 << endl;
    cout << "Input a2,b2,c2:"; cin >> a2>>b2>>c2;
    shiftRight3(a2, b2, c2);
    cout << "New numbers are " << a2 << setw(3) << b2 << setw(3) << c2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А если передавать по ссылке?

Answer (score 0):

```
 void shiftRight3(int a, int b, int c)
```

Вы передаете в функцию аргументы по значению, то есть КОПИИ переменных.

```
 void shiftRight3(int&a, int&b, int&c)
```

Так должно работать.